# Are "mp2v" and "mpgv" valid MPEG-2 codec tags in an MOV?

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime, mpeg

This question is related to [What is the correct MPEG-2 FourCC?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17526/what-is-the-correct-mpeg-2-fourcc) and to an open discussion [currently on the ffmpeg-user mailing list](https://ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.narkive.com/5qKNOLOF/mpeg-2-video-m2v1-vs-mp2v#post9):

> I am wondering if I should file a bug report about the MOV output. Open
> questions in that vein, though, are:
>
> ...
>
> - Is it a bug that mpg2 and mpgv cause MOV output to fail or is that
>   correct behavior?

There seem to be numerous possible tags in use for MPEG-2 video, in particular `m2v1`, `mp2v`, `mpg2`, and `mpgv`.

Now, ffmpeg fails with e.g. "Tag mpgv/0x7667706d incompatible with
output codec id '2' (m2v1)" when the output is MOV and either `mpg2` or `mpgv` is specified:

```
ffmpeg ... -vcodec mpeg2video -f mov ...             # succeeds (m1v1)
ffmpeg ... -vcodec mpeg2video -vtag mp2v -f mov ...  # succeeds
ffmpeg ... -vcodec mpeg2video -vtag mpg2 -f mov ...  # fails
ffmpeg ... -vcodec mpeg2video -vtag mpgv -f mov ...  # fails
```

All of those succeed for AVI. Ffmpeg's default tag for MPEG-2 in AVIs is `mpg2`.

Part of a bug report that I am writing for ffmpeg's MOV output handling may include the `mpg2` and `mpgv` failure behavior (with the desired behavior being success), but before I do that I need to be certain that this behavior is a bug rather than appropriate behavior.

So my question boils down to this: Are `mpg2` and `mpgv` valid, allowable alternative tags for MPEG-2 video **in an MOV file**, and are there others? I am looking for official Apple sources and MOV specifications rather than anecdotal evidence or lists of generally observed FourCC's / codec IDs.

I know that, at least [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats), MPEG-2 video in an MOV is an acceptable combination, I'm just not sure what the acceptable set of codec tags are in MOVs. This question is not about the "correct" MPEG-2 ID in general cases, it is about the allowable variants specifically in MOVs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPEG-2 doesn't seem to be an officially sanctioned codec for the Quicktime container. The official specification has a section related to [MPEG-1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap3/qtff3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH205-BBCGIJJI) in MOV but not MPEG-2. The US Library of Congress also does not have an entry for the [subtype](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000052.shtml) MPEG-2 in MOV, like it does for MPEG-1 (just called QTV_MPEG).

So, there's no official word on "allowable alternative tags". One can only examine MPEG-2 MOVs and see whether apps, specifically, Apple apps, play them or not and prepare a survey report. Since each app has its own fiat on whether it plays a file with a certain codec ID or not, that report whould be categorized by app i.e. VLC, Quicktime player. FCP..etc.

As an example, VLC recognizes the [following tags](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/9053b0919f00d88f16e1ef3e3f79b1cced74f742/src/misc/fourcc_list.h) for generic MPEG-2 i.e. not IMX or XDCAM:

```
    A("mpeg"),
    A("mp2v"),
    A("MPEG"),
    A("mpg2"),
    A("MPG2"),
    A("H262"),
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it wouldn't be easy. In the document you linked to [it says](http://apple.co/1PDDX8w) *"Table 4-1 shows some of the formats supported. The list is not exhaustive, and is subject to addition."* So while it doesn't define MPEG-2, it doesn't make it simple by explicitly disallowing it either. Further, I'm sure Apple software actually has been using it for some time. I know FCP X's "Compressor" does, and the ffmpeg source has a comment hinting that FCP 5 did. Still, the important thing is, `mp2v` and `mpgv` don't seem to be explicitly disallowed. I'll go with that.

Comment: "*list is not exhaustive*" -> true, but MPEG-2 was the dominant ISO format at the time of the original spec. That disclaimer probably covers niche codecs such as camcorders using some custom variant of MJPEG.